# How to replicate trunc function on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-2

I've search a bit before asking this question, but I haven't found the answer.
Is there a Trunc function on QGis? I've tried using floor, but it doesn't work (like I want) if the number is negative, for instance:

If

`$x=-8.639`

Floor will give me

`floor($x)=-9`

And what I'm looking to achieve is -8 (it's the trunc function).

(I'm passing angles to DMS notation)

I think this may be resolved with a conditional statement for negative values and positive values I also found this expression that makes the job `regexp_replace($x, '\\..*', '')`... but I guess there should be another (cleaner) way to do it.

I'm using QGis 2.0 on a 64bit Win7 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK!
Now I think I have this fully covered.

I think the formula to obtain the trunc value (for $x, for instance) is: `(abs(ceil($x))-abs(floor($x)))*floor(abs($x))`

.

The first part (`(abs(ceil($x))-abs(floor($x)))`) will determine the sign.

The second part (`floor(abs($x))`) will determine the value (using the absolute function).

Answer (score 3):

Field calculator accepts Python expressions. Unfortunately [`trunc()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html?highlight=trunc#math.trunc) is not available in Python (and so in field calculator) by default and you can't import math module inside field calculator. The easiest way to achieve your goal since `floor()` is working well is to increment your `$x` values with the high enough number `N` that ensures that in the end there will be a positive value for any of your coordinate, then `floor()` the result and finally decrement it by `N`. For example:

```
floor($x + 100000000) - 100000000
```

Comment: (+1) In general, because this approach strips half the precision off the value (leaving only eight significant digits (base 10) or so), it could create mistakes due to that precision loss.  Consider instead using a combination of `floor`, `abs`, and `copysign` (as discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986152/why-python-doesnt-have-a-sign-function).  In the present case, though, because the input is expected to be angles less than 360 in size, your answer works great if you just add 360 to `$x`.

Comment: @whuber, `copysign` is only available in `math` module, so it can't be used in this case.

Comment: Thanks--I had hoped it was native. In that case for general-purpose use one can solve the problem in a straightforward fashion with a conditional. In effect, `trunc(x)` is equivalent to `if(x<0) then -floor(-x) else floor(x)`.

Comment: @whuber, have you actually tested this? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: The formula I gave is correct and will work on any platform supporting a floor function. To avoid implementation problems you need to respect Python syntax, including its use of blanks for indentation.  (I do not use QGIS--this question illustrates one of many reasons why not--and so did not test anything. That's why I'm writing comments and not answers. :-)

Comment: @SS_Rebelious I've tried your solution (adding a great number, then flooring it and lastly decrement that great number again), but I didn't had great luck. I had the problem whuber stated that it would reduce the precision... but since it didn't work I decided to drop that solution. After that I also tried that `if(x<0)` solution... BUT (maybe because of my lack of experience on QGIS programming language I hasn't able to have it working. Lastly... I was able to reproduce the trunc function like this: `floor($x)+-1*(floor(-$x)-round(-$x))`

Comment: Please don't consider my previous comment... it's only partially correct, it doesn't work for all situations.